# Multiple Sent Actions From One Button?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I feel like this should be rather simple but my google-foo is failing me right now.  How can I have a button send actions to two things (in this case add a new Coredata object to an Array Controller and open the editing panel).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Call one method which does both things.

E.g.

```
- (void)doCoreDataStuff {
//Core Data Stuff
}

- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
[self doCoreDataStuff];
// Show the edit panel
}
```

Link it up to the second method...